# Calculate the difference between two dates. Swift 1.2

Tags: swift, nsdate, uilocalnotification, nscalendar

I need a way to find what time it will be after the "unknown" amount of time for the ore to be done.

After you start the timer it needs to calculate when to send the local notification. 
I need a way so the app can be completely closed and still notify them.

Thanks

This is the error I get when I implement the "***notificationsAllowed***" code.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the endtime you can use

```
timerEndTime = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:NSTimeInterval(oreWanted * 11))
```

So you get a `NSDate` object. Now you can fire a `UILocalNotification` at that calculated time:

**Note:** You need to ask for notification permissions when your app starts up. I have simplified this here with `notificationsAllowed` and `soundsAllowed` which are boolean variables in my AppDelegate.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate as! AppDelegate

if appDelegate.notificationsAllowed {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate = timerEndTime
    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    notification.alertBody = "Notification body text"
    notification.alertTitle = "Notification alert title"

    if appDelegate.soundsAllowed {
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    }

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Register the app for notifications in AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var notificationsAllowed = false
    var notificationSoundAllowed = false


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
        if notificationSettings.types & UIUserNotificationType.Alert != nil {
            self.notificationsAllowed = true
        }

        if notificationSettings.types & UIUserNotificationType.Sound != nil {
            self.notificationSoundAllowed = true
        }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you. If that was the solution, please mark the answer as correct by clicking on the hollow checkmark. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know a way so that the timer will keep going even when the user clicks the home button?

Comment: so the user can see how much time is left

Comment: Write the calculated endtime to `NSUserDefaults` and read it in the next time the users activates the app. So there is no need to keep the app running in the background.

Comment: but it needs to keep counting down while the app is closed.

Comment: It doesn't. When the app is opened again, you check what time it is and modify the timer. You can't rely on timer firing regularly anyway. It is always possible for a timer to miss sometimes. And of course your app can get killed while you are switched out.

Comment: could you help me, how to i get the current time and see how much time is left?

Comment: `NSDate.timeIntervalSinceNow` gives you the difference from now to the endtime. So you can use `timerEndTime.timeIntervalSinceNow` to get the remaining time.

Comment: I get a error, Look at the question for the error picture. Thanks For All Your Help!!

Comment: see the **Note** in my answer. These are variables I set in my appDelegate to indicate permissions for notifications. You need to ask for that permissions when your app starts up.

Comment: do you just do 'var notificationsAllowed = false'

Comment: I have updated my answer. Registering an app for notifications has nothing to do with your original question, so please read the basics on that topic. My updated answers shows my code how I do that for my app.

Comment: @zisoft  Ok, I would like to bother you for one more question. Thank you so much with all the help, the only problem is if you terminate the app then the counter doesn't continue counting down, But the notification will play, and when you open the app back up it will just start of where it was at. So is there a way to get the actual date and time and then a if statment to check if we are past that time or not.  One thing I think I forgot to mention is this if to help players of a different game called Rust,(PC Game).

Comment: @zisoft sorry one more question, is there a way to cancel the local notification after you called it?

Comment: `UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()`. Please read the documentation